# Springboot giving redundant fields with multiple tables native query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a native query in spring boot like this:

```
select
a.x,
a.y,
b.m,
b.n
from 
table1 a,
table2 b
where
a.x = b.x
order by a.x
```

here for each entry for table1 there can be multiple matching rows in table2. I.e there is OneToMany mapping.

for this i created an object to hold the data:

@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
@SecondaryTable(name = "table2", pkJoinColumns = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "x", referencedColumnName = "x")})
public class TableData {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "x")
public String x;


@Column(name = "y")
public String y;


@Column(name = "m", table = "table2")
public String m;


@Column(name = "n", table = "table2")
public String n;

//getters and setters
```

When i execute the sql in my db i see the results coming fine. I.e i see two different rows with same a.x but with different b.m and b.n

But my json response has two identical rows with same a.x and same b.m and b.n

Sample data:

table1:
ManagerID|ManagerName|Role
'1','John','Manager'

table2:
ManagerID|AssociateName|AssociateId
'1','Peter','2'
'1','Jacob','3'

Expected output

'1','John','Peter','2'
'1','John','Jacob','3'

Output i am seeing right now:

'1','John','Peter','2'
'1','John','Peter','2'

Any guess where i am getting wrong ??

Comment: Can you add some sample data for each table along with expected output vs current output

Comment: Please find the updates with sample data above

Answer (score 0):

My problem got resolved by using the @IdClass annotation as the resulting data from the query was a join and the uniqueness can be maintained by a combination of fields !!